# PHP fgets() returns only the first line of the file

Tags: php

I have a script to show the content of a file (user.css), and I'm using `fgets()`
The problem is than it returns only the first line of the content of the file.

user.css file content :

```
body {
background: #eee;
}
```

PHP output :

```
body {
```

PHP Code :

```
$file_handle = fopen("css/user.css", "r");
$txt = fgets($file_handle);
return $txt;
fclose($file_handle);
```

Any help please ?
**Cheers, MrZ**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: Did you check the PHP manual before you posted here? That's what `fgets()` does. You want [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Hobo said you can `use file_get_content()` or read it line by line using fgets() in a loop. Example:

```
<?php 

 $handle = fopen("css/user.css", "r");
 while(feof($handle)) !== true {
     echo fgets($handle);
 }
 fclose($handle);
```